# Django admin with CMS functionality

Tags: django, django-admin, content-management-system

The Django admin interface is pretty basic, useful for occasional administration only. Once dealing with larger numbers of more complex objects, it becomes unwieldy. To give one example, foreign objects by default appear in a small multi select box with their title only as the label.

Many developers add the required admin functionality through their own forms, but these stand separate to the admin interface and often have to reinvent the wheel with the same CMS like behaviour each time.

Are there any packages that extend the admin interface with rich functionality, without going over to a complete CMS solution like Django CMS?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's entirely what you're looking for, but JET extends the admin panel functionality. You can check their [github repo](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet) to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: FWIW, the label of foreign keys is whatever you define in the model's `__str__` function. The multi-select boxes are not pretty for large lists, I agree.